# winforms c# проблема версиями .Net Framework

Tags: c#

приложение должен работать по локальной сети, в одних компьютерах запускается где версия framework 4.6.x . проблема в том что есть старые компьютеры с операционной системой под ХР и старыми версиями Framework.там где стоит .NET 3.5 не открывается

можно ли решить проблему с настройки конфигурации app.config?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131482/discussion-on-question-by-mister-junior-winforms-c---net-frame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже лучшим решением здесь будет сделать откат версии .NET Framework в приложении до .NET 3.5, если это возможно. Если нет, в качестве "костыля" можете попробовать удалить supportedRuntime если он присутствует в app.config файле и посмотреть, запустится ли приложение. Теоретически это должно сработать но имейте ввиду что если приложение вызывает функции .NET 4.5 то они все равно будут падать.

Comment: попробую , или же заново сделать для 3.5 , только еще надо найти библиотеки под ним